# Android Java Changing Fragment from within Fragment Instead of Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to change a fragment from the onclick listener of a button in another fragment instead of the activity that is holding the Fragments. So far I've tried:

1.

```
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, new searchResults());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
```

2. I've also tried removing the parent view before the code above.

   ```
   if (v.getParent() != null) {
      ((ViewGroup)(v.getParent())).removeView(v);
   ```
3. I've been suggested to use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getActivity()` but `getSupportFragmentManager()` does not work with that.

All three of the above mentioned solutions give the same exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rehnsehan, PID: 10913
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Kindly help me with a solution to making this work or a suggestion on how I can handle such functionality in the fragment activity, Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've shifted my approach to handling the event in the activity instead of the fragment. Bad news, I still get the same exception.
Good news, I might be a lil closer to the what's causing this.

**UPDATED STACK TRACE**

Adding logs everywhere to get a sense of what's happening, I've found out that the exception occurs in the `OnCreateView()` of fragment B.

```
D/searchresults: oncreateview
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rehnsehan, PID: 16413
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
....
```

**OnCreateView() Code**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_results,container,false);
        if (v.getParent() != null) {
            Log.d("searchresults","oncreateview parent check");
            ((ViewGroup) (v.getParent())).removeView(v);
            Log.d("searchresults","oncreateview after remove parent");

        }
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_results,container);
        Log.d("searchresults","oncreateview");
        return v;
    }
```

The control never goes to the if condition where I check if the parent is not null.
This is where we are right now, hopefully more troubleshooting helps us find a solution soon.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the fragment from a different fragment and not making the activity be the decision maker?

Comment: @tomerpacific This is going to be hard to explain but I'll try, I'm using a bottom navigation bar so everything is a fragment. In one of those fragments, let's say searchFragment, I've a button that get's location and shows the nearby results. I want to show the results in a new fragment. Since the button That starts this whole thing is in the fragment and not in the activity, I'm doing it in the fragment. I hope that was enough explanation, this thing's almost fried my brain by now lol